# Update Work Flow Task Status Sp 365 E3

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, office-365

I have a Web Page based on SharePoint 365 E3 with InfoPath 2013.

I need to Get and Update the Status of (WorkFlow Task) List through Custom Code - C#.

I tried to access this using CSOM but it returns critical Error (CSOM required full Trust) which is not available in SP 365.

Comment: Show your CSOM code please

Comment: @Atish please find following connection
public void CTRL1_2_Clicked(object sender, ClickedEventArgs e){
Uri sharepointUrl = new Uri("https://mySPSite.sharepoint.com/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/Leave%20Request");
ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(sharepointUrl);
}